# Join array contents into an 'English list'

Tags: ruby, arrays

I like to join an array resulting in an 'English list'. For example `['one', 'two', 'three']` should result in `'one, two and three'`.

I wrote this code to achieve it (assuming that the array is not empty, which is not the case in my situation)

```
if array.length == 1
  result = array[0]
else
  result = "#{array[0, array.length].join(', ')} and #{array.last}"
end
```

But I was wondering whether there exists some 'advanced' join method to achieve this behaviour? Or at least some shorter/nicer code?

Comment: just wondering, is this project euler?

Comment: So you're asking "Is there a join method that uses one delimiter for most of the stuff, but a different one for the last element"?

What purpose would that have in a core library?

Comment: @Anurag no it is not project euler (haven't seen such a question, but it was quite a long time ago I looked at it), but even though it would be solved by my code I guess, so no need to ask?

Comment: @Anon. yes, that is what I'm asking. What is purpose would be in a core library I do not know, but I need that kind functionality in multiple places in my application. So I thought maybe others need it as well and thus maybe such a method is available.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Such a method doesn't exist in core Ruby.

It *has* been [implemented](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-0-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/conversions.rb) in Rails' Active Support library, though:

```
['one', 'two', 'three'].to_sentence
#=> "one, two, and three"
```

The delimiters are configurable, and it also uses Rails' I18n by default.

If you use ActiveSupport or Rails, this would be the preferred way to do it. If your application is non-Railsy, your implementation seems fine for English-only purposes.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I did not know that such a method would be implemented in Rails (and not Ruby) or I would have added a comment that I was using Rails

Comment: The link is broken. And just to really nit-pick, your version has an Oxford comma (the comma between two and three), whereas the OP doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, the link has been updated. The delimiters are configurable like I mentioned. I just showed the default.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 8):

Just as a readability hint. You can write

```
array[0...-1]
```

to select all but the last element.

*Edit, updated the code example with Nick's suggestion.*

Comment: Did not know that (I am still new to Ruby), but it is indeed better readable

Comment: If you glance over the code, you could miss the 3 dots. I'd rather use `array[0..-2]`.